# Webpack 2 - is it bad practice to use "vendors" bundle?

Tags: webpack

I have the following type of configuration which creates bundles:

```
{
  entry: {
    main: 'src/main.js',
    vendor: [ 'lodash', 'react' ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: Infinity,
    })
  ] 
}
```

As you can see my intention is to split out my vendor modules into separate bundles.  This works as expected however I have noticed that tree-shaking does not seem to occur in this case.  When I use this vendors approach the entire module will be included in the vendor bundles even if my source isn't using them.

If I don't use the vendors approach the total bundle size is significantly smaller.

Is this expected behaviour? And if so is it then considered bad practice to use this technique should you wish to take advantage of tree shaking?

Comment: That could be a bug. It's probably worth it to [open a bug report](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/new) to know for sure.

Comment: encounter the same problems. after using the ```CommonsChunkPlugin``` to split the vendor bundle, tree shaking is not longer working.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, since it's kind of a "no two builds are the same" type of thing, but we noticed a similar issue when we were using the commons chunk plugin.

I believe the size increase and apparent lack of tree shaking is because some packages may be included in both the main and vendor entry points - lots of those small common utility packages, for example. With one entry point, Webpack will dedupe them, but it won't know that things required by the main entry are already required by the vendor entry unless you add them specifically.

Our solution, in a build similar to yours, was to simply not use the vendor plugin. The build takes a bit longer but the result is smaller. I believe the commons chunk plugin is primarily designed for cases where you may have several entry points.